# Definition for global variables in VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, macros, projects-and-solutions, definition

Where are 'global macros' for VS2010 project properties defined ?

With global macros, i mean the variables after a $ sign, for instance in

```
$(SolutionDir)My_build\$(ProjectName)\$(Configuration)\$(Platform)\objects\
```

Where are `SolutionDir`, `ProjectName` defined ?

The line i mention as an example is in the Intermediate Directory properties in VS2010 project properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this has changed (I'm using VS 2013)

Right click your project and select "Properties"

Click "Build Events"

Click "Edit Pre-build..."

Click "Macros >>"

There they are.

Comment: I think OP is more interested in where they are defined, not where to see them. :)

Comment: @herohuyongtao - Where are they defined?   That would be Redmond, Washington :)

Answer (score 2):

These are **macros for build commands and properties** that come along with Visual Studio.

You can use these macros anywhere in a project's **Property Pages** dialog box where strings are accepted. These macros are not case sensitive.

To display the currently available macros, in the column to the right of a property name, click the drop-down arrow. If **Edit** is available, click it and then in the edit dialog box, click **Macros**. For more information, see the **Specifying User-Defined Values** section of [Property Pages (C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/675f1588%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Check out [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more info.